# Searching Hierarchical List for a Name (a Named Matrix) and Placing Output in an Array or List (r)

Tags: r, list, search, matrix, hierarchy

I have a complex hierarchical set of lists, within which are stored multiple matrices. I would like to store all those matrices in either an array or a list.

I say array or list because I'm not sure, but presumably storing the 'path' to the matrix in an array will be faster than duplicating all the matrices into a new list.

Here is how to create the list hierarchy:

```
Kings = c('Alfred the Great', 'Edgar the Peaceful', 'Edmund Ironside', 'Harold Godwinson')
DataSets <- c('KingDF', 'KingDFMtx', 'KingMtx')

KingList <- lapply(Kings, function(K) {
  ret <- rep(tibble(setNames(vector("list", length(DataSets)), 
                           DataSets)), 
             length(Kings))
  setNames(ret, 
           paste0(K, " vs ", Kings)) 
})
names(KingList) <- Kings
str(KingList)
```

So this will give you a list of Kings, with a list inside each of those lists comparing the kings, and inside those, a list of various data formats.

So for instance I have a list 'path' that looks like this:

```
KingsList[['Alfred the Great']][['Alfred the Great vs Edgar the Peaceful']][['KingMtx']]
```

and another that looks like this:

```
KingsList[['Edmund Ironside']][['Edmund Ironside vs Harrold Goodwinson']][['KingMtx']]
```

And I want an array or list which collects all the 'KingsMtx' matrices, with the intent to use this to create one large unified matrix which includes all the data.

However the `search.list` function returns a list of every single data point within a matrix named 'KingMtx', thus returning a jumble of hundred of integers in a rather unhelpful list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your list looks like this:

```
KingList <- lapply(Kings, function(K) {
  vs.list <- lapply(paste0(K, " vs ", Kings), function(x){ ds.list <- lapply(DataSets, function(y){matrix(1:6, nrow=2)}); setNames(ds.list, DataSets)})
 setNames(vs.list, paste0(K, " vs ", Kings))
})
names(KingList) <- Kings
str(KingList)
```

You can get a list of all the matrices like this:

```
unlisted <- unlist(unlist(KingList, recursive = F), recursive = F)
```

To get only matrices `KingMtx` do:

```
KingMtx <- unlisted[grep('\\.KingMtx$', names(unlisted), value = T)]
names(KingMtx) <- sub('\\.KingMtx$', '', names(KingMtx))
```

And to get this back into 1 data.frame:

```
KingDF <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(names(KingMtx), function(name){
  d <- as.data.frame(KingMtx[[name]])
  n.split <- strsplit(name, '\\.')[[1]]
  d$King <- n.split[1]
  d$opponent <- strsplit(n.split[2], ' vs ')[[1]]
  d
})))
```